# Exception from IBM ILOG concert: can not read data from excel

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, cplex, ilog

I am using IBM Cplex studio IDE to solve an optimization problem called location set covering problem with backup, I have coded the model and solved it for a small problem, which works fine. When I am embarking a large datasets from excel (more than 8,000 nodes or a graph with 71, 000,000 elements) the IDE gives me this error, which really frustrating me.

The error is " Exception from IBM ILOG Concert: can not read data from excel"

It should be noted that when I am loading this data into CPLEX, its size is around 1GB.

I would appreciate for any tips in the case.

Regards.

The error is " Exception from IBM ILOG Concert: can not read data from excel"

Answer (score 0):

For large data sets in excel you may try to load subsets as can be seen at https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/oplexcel/blob/main/hugexlsread.mod

```
 //parameters
{string} plz = ...;
{string} SU = ...;




float travelTime1[plz][1..1999]=... ;
float travelTime2[plz][2000..3999]=... ;

float travelTime3[plz][4000..5999]=... ;

float travelTime4[plz][6000..7999]=... ;

float travelTime5[plz][8000..8176]=... ;


int einwohner [plz] ; //= ...;

//float travelTime[plz][SU]=... ; // this does not work

float travelTimeA[p in plz][s in 1..8176]=(s in 1..1999)?travelTime1[p][s]:
((s in 2000..3999)?travelTime2[p][s]:
((s in 4000..5999)?travelTime3[p][s]:
((s in 6000..7999)?travelTime4[p][s]:
((s in 8000..10000)?travelTime5[p][s]:0
))));

float travelTime[p in plz][su in SU]= travelTimeA[p][ord(SU,su)+1];

execute
{
  travelTime
}
```

Comment: Hi Alex,

Thanks for that prompt answer. 
Could you please take a look on my code and kindly let me know how can I tweak the code:

I define the parameter distance_matrix in the mode file as follows:

      int n= ...; 
range demand_nodes = 1..n;
range potentialLoc = 1 .. n;


float distance_matrix[demand_nodes][potentialLoc] = ...;

this is the way I am initializing this parameter from the exce.
n= 8459;  
distance_matrix from SheetRead(data_sheet,"data!A1:LMI8459"); 

Now my question is how should I include the above comment into mine.

Thanks a lot for your help!